# Django. Как вывести тэги в шаблоне?

Tags: python, django

Подключил [django-taggit](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit) к блогу. Хочу вывести определенный набор тегов под каждой статьей, используя `{{ article.tags.names }}`. В шаблоне - получаю список тэгов под статьей `['linux', 'python', 'english']`. Как можно исправить это?

**views.py**:

```
def index(request):
 lastet_articles_list = Article.objects.order_by('-pub_date')
 list_of_tags = []
 for obj in lastet_articles_list:
    list_of_tags += obj.tags.names()
 list_of_tags = list(set(list_of_tags))
 context = {
    'lastet_articles_list': lastet_articles_list,
    'list_of_tags': list_of_tags,
 }
 return render(request, 'article/index.html', context)
```

(`list_of_tags` здесь использую, чтобы просто вывести имеющиеся тэги на сайте)

**index.html**:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    {% if lastet_articles_list %}
        {% for article in lastet_articles_list %}
            <div class="post-preview">
                <a href="/article/{{ article.id }}/">{{ article.title }}</a>
                <p class="post-meta">{{ article.tags.names }}</p>
                <p class="post-meta">Posted {{ article.pub_date }}</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

**models.py**:

```
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager


class Article(models.Model):
 title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
 text = models.TextField()
 tags = TaggableManager()
```

Comment: Воспроизвел ваш пример. У меня все выводится правильно. Что такое `article.tags`, какой тип данных? Можно скриншот вывода посмотреть?

Comment: @Max тип данных <class 'taggit.managers._TaggableManager'>, скриншот вывода: [ссылка](http://uploads.ru/VxklP.png)

Comment: @Max в первом случае я пишу `obj.tags.names()` чтобы получить все имеющиеся тэги, дописал модель выше

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все правильно, метод **names** возвращает массив имен тэгов. Выводите их по одному в вашем блоге.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эксперимент, чтобы понять как это работает:

```
>>> from Tasks.models import Post
>>> p = Post.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> p.tags
<taggit.managers._TaggableManager object at 0x7f0f05ecdf28>
>>> p.tags.add('cat', 'dog')
>>> p.save()
>>> p.tags.names
<bound method _TaggableManager.names of <taggit.managers._TaggableManager object at 0x7f0effcbceb8>>
>>> p.tags.names()
['cat', 'dog']
>>> for name in p.tags.names():
...     print(name)
... 
cat
dog
>>> p = Post()
>>> p.title = 'Post 2'
>>> p.text = 'second post'
>>> p.save()
>>> p.pk
2
>>> p.tags.add('cat')
>>> p.save()
>>> Post.objects.filter(tags__name__in=["cat"])
[<Post: Post object>, <Post: Post object>]
>>> Post.objects.filter(tags__name__in=["dog"])
[<Post: Post object>]
```